# Using os.remove in ArcGIS Python script tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, error-000601

I have a Python script that I want to turn into a scripting tool in ArcGIS.  Part of the script creates several SDE database connection files, creates a versions using those connection files, and then deletes the connection files.

To delete the connection files, I'm using `os.remove(connections)`.  This works as expected in PyScripter and the Python window in ArcMap.  However, when I create a scripting tool and try to run it, it returns the message, "System cannot find the path specified" in reference to this line.

I can modify the code to say

```
if os.path.exists(connections):
    os.remove(connections)
```

so that it will move on to the next step, but then  I am left with a folder full of connection files when the tool is finished running.

Any suggestions?

I tried arcpy's Delete, but got Error 000601 that it may be locked by another application.  I found [this bug](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMTAxMjIw) which says that this is a bug with arcpy.Delete_management in ArcMap 10.2.1 (which I am using), and suggests using os.remove() instead.

Comment: Have you tired the function arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management()

Comment: It'll disconnect idle enterprise geodatabase connections http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/clear-workspace-cache.htm

Comment: Unfortunately arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management() isn't working for me either. It doesn't work in the standalone script either, though, so I probably just need to work on how I'm using arcpy.env.workspace.  It's frustrating that os.remove() doesn't work since it's so simple and easily implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Clear Workspace Cache tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Clear_Workspace_Cache/00170000000m000000/).

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"SDEConnection" 
env.workspace = "" 
arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management(r"SDEConnection")
```

If you do not specify a connection variable in the function all connections will be removed from the Cache